# How to change DefaultTasksMax in system.conf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to change the `DefaultTasksMax` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` but won't change.

The command:

```
systemctl show --property=DefaultTasksMax
```

still (even after server restart) produces this output:

```
DefaultTasksMax=105
```

What am I doing wrong?

Some other informations: the server is hosted on Strato.com, it runs Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was just stupid, I forgot to remove the `#` before the statement.